# Sistema de login para sorteio em php

Tags: php

Estou precisando criar um sistema de login para uma página de sorteio. 
O user tem que ser o número que sera sorteado, essa informação já vai estar alimentada no BD, então o usuário entraria com esse número e o e-mail para se logar e ter acesso ao conteúdo da página. Por exemplo ao carregar a página terá o campo código do sorteio e o e-mail, ai esse código já estará no BD e ele precisaria alimentar só com o e-mail dele e pronto já estaria logado. Alguma ideia em como criar esse login que funciona como cadastro também?

Comment: Tem alguma coisa já feita, código, estrutura de banco

Answer (score 1):

Penso que mais simples que fazer um sistema de cadastro completo com validação do email, seria você permitir o usuário se identificar com a sua conta do Facebook, Google, Microsoft, Yahoo, etc..

Para isso você pode usar OAuth porque esse protocolo permite você acessar aos dados da conta e obter o email do usuário com a sua permissão.

Aí você já cria a conta do usuário no seu site se o email ainda não existir no seu banco de dados.

O protocolo OAuth é um pouco complicado e por isso eu mesmo escrevi uma [classe de cliente OAuth em PHP](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html) para simplificar o processo de autorização e acesso a APIs baseadas em OAuth como Facebook, Google, etc.. Aqui tem a [primeira](http://imasters.com.br/infra/seguranca/oauth-sem-dor-com-php-php-oauth-api-parte-01/) e a [segunda parte](http://imasters.com.br/infra/seguranca/oauth-sem-dor-com-php-php-oauth-api-parte-02/) de um tutorial em Português sobre este assunto.

Answer (score 0):

pelo que eu entendi você terá que fazer o seguinte, isso assumindo que esta usando mysql:

```
$numero = "numero do sorteio";

$email = "email digitado";

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE numero = '{$numero}'") or die (mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){

    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tabela set email = '{$email}' WHERE numero = '{$numero}'") or die (mysql_error());

}
```

Comment: Certo acho que entendi, vou tentar aqui, pois fiz um sistema de login, baseado nesse [link](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criando-um-sistema-de-login-com-php-e-mysql/) E agora vou implementar a confirmação de email, pois quando o email não tiver cadastrado na própria página de login vou cadastrar o email e enviar a confirmação.

Comment: você diz enviar uma confirmação por email? para ele clicar no link e confirmar o cadastro?

Comment: Exatamente confirmação de e-mail!

Comment: para fazer isso você precisa armazenar as informações em uma tabela temporária, nesta tabela você colocaria o email da pessoa criptografado, exemplo com md5. Após isto você faz o php enviar um e-mail para a pessoa com um link de confirmação exemplo: www.site.com/valida.php?email=fsd56f4fsdf564sd6f4 onde o valor do get seria o email da pessoa criptografado, assim que a pessoa abrir este link você verifica o email e caso ele esteja correto você transfere todos os dados dele que estão na tabela de dados temporarios para a tabela de acesso.